# Pass array of structs by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I would like to pass an array of structs to a function.

```
struct Month {
    std::string name;
    int days;
};

Month months[12]{{"January", 31}, {"February", 28}, {"March", 31}, {"April", 30}, {"May", 31}, {"June", 30},
    {"July", 31}, {"August", 31}, {"September", 30}, {"October", 31}, {"November", 30}, {"December", 31}};
```

I have tried to pass the months array to functions with the parameter: Month (&months)[]

The compiler noted: "no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘main()::Month [12]’ to ‘Month (&)[12]’".

I then attempted to pass the array by a pointer and to do this I first allocated the elements of the months array on the free-store as shown below.

```
Month* months[12]{new Month{"January", 31}, new Month{"February", 28}, new Month{"March", 31}, new Month{"April", 30}, new Month{"May", 31}, new Month{"June", 30},
    new Month{"July", 31}, new Month{"August", 31}, new Month{"September", 30}, new Month{"October", 31}, new Month{"November", 30}, new Month{"December", 31}};
```

I tried to pass this array to a function with the parameter: Month**

The compiler stated: "no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘main()::Month* [12]’ to ‘Month**’"

I would like to know how I could pass my months array by pointer and if it is possible to pass it by reference as well.

And yes, I do know that using a vector would be a lot easier but I just started learning C++ a few days ago and I would like to become familiarized with the arrays.

The function itself is empty, I cannot write the function without knowing what my parameter will be.

```
void print_table(Month** months) {

}
```

And the function call is:

```
print_table(months)
```

After removing all extraneous code I was left with this:

```
struct Month;
void print_table(Month** months);

int main() {
    struct Month {
        std::string name;
        int days;
    }

    Month* months[12]{new Month{"January", 31}, new Month{"February", 28}, new Month{"March", 31}, new Month{"April", 30}, new Month{"May", 31}, new Month{"June", 30},
        new Month{"July", 31}, new Month{"August", 31}, new Month{"September", 30}, new Month{"October", 31}, new Month{"November", 30}, new Month{"December", 31}};
    print_table(months);
}
```

The issue was explained in the comments by john, I have also posted the corrected code.

Comment: Since this is C++, please, *please* start learning about `std::vector` and how you can `emplace_back` without using pointers. `std::vector<Month>` can be passed in as a simple reference. As a bonus it handles memory management for you.

Comment: Since all you have shown us is how you declared the array, but not the code for the function or the function call it's very hard to say what you did wrong. Please show the code that causes these errors.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @tadman I have already started to learn about vectors but the exercise I am doing requires that I use an array of structures.

Comment: At the moment I can't see any reason that either version wouldn't work, please show how you are calling this function (and yes the content of the function is irrelevent).

Comment: Yet another C++ course that completely fails to teach the language, and instead goes down some ridiculous "fancy C" rabbit hole. I hope you survive without picking up too many bad habits! To learn C++ properly you have to start with the Standard Library as those tools are absolutely essential.

Comment: Read [Array-to-pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay), make `void print_table(const Month* months)` and enjoy.

Comment: @EricLeus Sorry Eric but I can't reproduce your problem, as you can see here http://cpp.sh/2pg55 the code you have posted compiles perfectly well. There's a reason we ask people to post *complete* code because all to often they don't post the code that is really causing the error.

Comment: @EricLeus So remove all the extraneous material from your program, edit the above question, and post a complete program, should be only a few lines long. And then someone will tell you what the real problem is.

Comment: @john Sorry about that! thought that it would be easier to post the "relevant" code but now I know that the problem is usually not what you originally think it is. I declared the struct outside of the main function and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @EricLeus Yes, you have two different structs one inside of main and one global. They had the same name but were different. Local structs are very rarely used, declare all your structs outside of any function.

Comment: @EricLeus Your first attempt, without pointers and using a reference, should work as well now. That would be my preference, avoid pointers if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will treat the content of `Month` as constant, simply pass a rvalue reference, e.g. `Month*&& m`. Example:

```
void showmonths (Month*&& m, size_t nmonths)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nmonths; i++)
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(12) << m[i].name << m[i].days << '\n';
}
```

For further details on the declaration and use of references, see: [Reference declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

Answer (score 0):

After reading john's comment I realized that the issue was that my struct was declared inside of the main function as shown here:

```
struct Month;
void print_table(Month** months);

int main() {
    struct Month {
        std::string name;
        int days;
    }

    Month* months[12]{new Month{"January", 31}, new Month{"February", 28}, new Month{"March", 31}, new Month{"April", 30}, new Month{"May", 31}, new Month{"June", 30},
        new Month{"July", 31}, new Month{"August", 31}, new Month{"September", 30}, new Month{"October", 31}, new Month{"November", 30}, new Month{"December", 31}};
    print_table(months);
}
```

I edited to declare the struct outside of the main function and it worked. Thanks!

```
struct Month {
    std::string name;
    int days;
}
void print_table(Month** months);

int main() {
    Month* months[12]{new Month{"January", 31}, new Month{"February", 28}, new Month{"March", 31}, new Month{"April", 30}, new Month{"May", 31}, new Month{"June", 30},
        new Month{"July", 31}, new Month{"August", 31}, new Month{"September", 30}, new Month{"October", 31}, new Month{"November", 30}, new Month{"December", 31}};
    print_table(months);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
Month months[10];
//like this you can pass
print_table(months);
```

**Pass to this function**

```
void print_table(struct Month * months)
{
   //code here
}
```

Comment: No, `months` not `months[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You declare yet another `struct Month`. You will get a compiler warning.